# How to convert blob into image to preprocess and recognition in flask or django?

Tags: python, flask, webrtc

I am working on a Project which involves real-time video streaming and gesture recognition. however, I found lots of resources to get a real-time video stream from client-side to server-side, but nothing works fast and simple to implement. I have tried AIORTC, but I don't understand.

I don't know how to use webRTC in Django or Flask for such a task, please help me if you have any kind of idea about webRTC with python. Or help me to resolve this issue,

I am trying to get frames from javascript to flask as a blob, but I don't know how to recreate image from a blob,
I have tried `base64.b64decode()` but it doesn't work.

here is my getImage.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Post an Image test</title>
        <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        /* mirror the image */
        video, canvas {
        transform: scale(-1, 1); /*For Firefox (& IE) */
        -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1); /*for Chrome & Opera (& Safari) */
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <video id="myVideo" height="480" width="640" autoplay></video>
    
    <script>
    
        let v = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    
        //create a canvas to grab an image for upload
        let imageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        let imageCtx = imageCanvas.getContext("2d");
    
        //Add file blob to a form and post
        function postFile(file) {
            let formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("image", file);
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/image', true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200)
                    console.log(this.response);
                else
                    console.error(xhr);
            };
            xhr.send(formdata);
        }
    
        //Get the image from the canvas
        function sendImagefromCanvas() {
    
            //Make sure the canvas is set to the current video size
            imageCanvas.width = v.videoWidth;
            imageCanvas.height = v.videoHeight;
    
            imageCtx.drawImage(v, 0, 0, v.videoWidth, v.videoHeight);
    
            //Convert the canvas to blob and post the file
            imageCanvas.toBlob(postFile, 'image/jpeg');
        }
    
        //Take a picture on click
        v.onclick = function() {
            console.log('click');
            sendImagefromCanvas();
        };
    
        window.onload = function () {
    
            //Get camera video
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width: 640, height: 480}, audio: false})
                .then(stream => {
                    v.srcObject = stream;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', err)
                });
    
        };
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is server.py file

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import time
import base64
import cv2
import base64

PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = './images'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return Response(open('./static/getImage.html').read(), mimetype="text/html")

# save the image as a picture
@app.route('/image', methods=['POST'])
def image():

    blob = request.files['image']  # get the image
    f = ('%s.jpeg' % time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
    print("images saved!!!!!!!")
    print(blob)
    blob.save('%s/%s' % (PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, "realTime.jpeg"))
    data=base64.b64decode(blob)
    print(data)
    return Response("%s saved" % f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost')
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a cross origin policy. Make sure that.

In `blob = request.files['image']  # get the image`
it looks like you need:

```
blob = request.files['image'].read()
```